# Calling an enum variable in Java

Tags: java, enums

I'm working on a JPanel project where you play the computer in Rock, Paper, Scissors. I'm using an enum for the choices. I have it set up like so

```
enum Choices {rock, paper, scissors}
```

And now, to set the "players choice" to be whatever button they press, I have

```
if (event.getSource() == rock){        //Makes it so when you press rock button, your choice is rock
    Choice playerChoice = Choice.rock; 
}
```

But now when I try to do

```
if (playerChoice == Choice.rock)
    if (cpuChoice == Choice.scissors)
        playerWon = true;
```

.. and so on for each of the options, I get an error on "playerChoice" saying it cannot find symbol. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Edit: It was suggested "Using variables outside of an if statement", but on that, the person was initializing and instantiating the variable inside. I have already initialized it the enum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the scope of your `Choice playerChoice`.

So do:

```
Choice playerChoice
if (event.getSource() == rock){ 
   playerChoice = Choice.rock; 
}

if (playerChoice == Choice.rock)
    if (cpuChoice == Choice.scissors)
        playerWon = true;
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. the enum name and the test are the same, I did not mean to add the "s" in the enum name

Comment: @Cythix I updated my answer.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you very much